# "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post" for correcting an inaccuracy

Tags: discussion, review

My edit at https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/152809 was refused by @Willeke with the reason

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I'm confused with this - all I did was to correct an inaccurate statement made by the person that wrote the answer and don't believe that it fits the above reason. The statement that I removed wasn't correct when the answer was written either.

I reviewed similar questions with this reason but couldn't find a similar example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Edits are not for correcting information in the answers (or questions.)
That is the reason the edit was rejected.

If you do not agree with the information in an answer you can comment with what you think is the correct information. Or you can post your own answer with the correct, in your view, information.

People checking edits will usually not know which user is more knowledgeable and can not trust edits to really improve the information, which is why we have that rule.

Small edits that correct obvious mistakes are often accepted, bigger edits not.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/editing does not disallow editing to correct minor mistakes. Is that not the case here?

Also in any case the reason needs to be more descriptive - such as "edits are not for correcting information in the answers"

Comment: Got to agree with @Leaderboard here.  This edit does NOT substantially change the answer, but it absolutely does correct/improve it. The question was about airlines that currently allow smoking. Concorde hasn't flown for 20 years, so any part of the answer related to it isn't overly relevant anyway.  10 seconds of research shows that Concorde did NOT always allow smoking - in fact Harvey Weinstein was famously detained/fined for smoking on Concorde after it was banned.  And to top everything off, the link to the nytimes is paywalled, so not available to most people anyway.

Comment: @Doc, remains how people approving edits can judge whom is the more knowledgeable person, OP or the one proposing the edit. They cannot know, as they do not know these people and they do not (need to) have the knowledge on the subject matter. Remains that edits are not for correcting information in the posts, comments or rivalling answers are the way to go.

Comment: @Willeke It's worth pointing out that the very last comment on that answer, from none other than Mark Mayo, states "I agree about accuracy, and you're welcome to update answers, but commenting isn't always as helpful, as they get lost in the noise sometimes".   Also worth mentioning that Leaderboard included a link in the comment to their update that verified the update.